# Error when copying a blob from one container to another, the content final is 0 bytes in C#

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am working on a project to move a blob from one container to another, using azure functions with C#, I have tried different ways to copy the file from one container to another, however it has only been possible to move the name and extension but when downloading or trying to access the file the content is 0 bytes.

This is the code currently implemented.

```
namespace TestInput
{
    [StorageAccount ("BlobConnectionString")]
    public class TestInput
    {
        [FunctionName("TestInput")]
        public static void Run(
            [BlobTrigger("test/{name}")] Stream myBlob,
            [Blob("testoutput/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream outputBlob,
            string name,
            
                            ILogger log)
        {
            
            var accountName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AccountName");
            var accountKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AccountKey");
            var cred = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
            var account = new CloudStorageAccount(cred, true);
            var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var sourceContainer = client.GetContainerReference("test");
            var sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference($"{name}");
            var destinationContainer = client.GetContainerReference("testoutput");
            var destinationBlob = destinationContainer.GetBlockBlobReference($"{name}");
            destinationBlob.UploadFromStream(myBlob);
            sourceBlob.Delete(DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots);
            
        }
    }

}
```

I would be grateful if you could tell me how to solve this problem or what parameter I am missing.

Comment: What happens if you don't delete the source blob? Also, what's the .Position in myBlob?

Comment: Hi Leonardo    
myBlob is taking the blob or file loaded in the source container. In this case the trigger is every time a new file is uploaded to the initial container. The final step of removing the blob from the initial container is just an add-on, if I remove it it does not affect the process of copying the blob from one container to another.

Comment: Did you try `myBlob.Position = 0;` before reading it?

Answer (score 0):

**Please Check if the below code helps to copy a blob from one container to another using Azure Function:**

Below is the .NET 6 Azure Function of type Blob Storage Trigger:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

namespace KrishBlobTriggerAF1205
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task RunAsync([BlobTrigger("dev/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log,
            [Blob("staging/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream outputBlob)
        {
            var srcconnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage");
            string sourceContainer = "source";
            string targetContainer = "target";
            string blobName = "blob-name.txt";


            BlobServiceClient serviceClient = new BlobServiceClient(srcconnectionString);
            BlobContainerClient sourceContainerClient = serviceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(sourceContainer);
            BlobContainerClient targetContainerClient = serviceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(targetContainer);
            BlobClient sourceBlobClient = sourceContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);
            BlobClient targetBlobClient = targetContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);
            log.LogInformation("Sending copy blob request....");
            var result = await targetBlobClient.StartCopyFromUriAsync(sourceBlobClient.Uri);
            log.LogInformation("Copy blob request sent....");
            log.LogInformation("============");
            bool isBlobCopiedSuccessfully = false;
            do
            {
                log.LogInformation("Checking copy status....");
                var targetBlobProperties = await targetBlobClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
                log.LogInformation($"Current copy status = {targetBlobProperties.Value.CopyStatus}");
                if (targetBlobProperties.Value.CopyStatus.Equals(CopyStatus.Pending))
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                else
                {
                    isBlobCopiedSuccessfully = targetBlobProperties.Value.CopyStatus.Equals(CopyStatus.Success);
                    break;
                }
            } while (true);

            if (isBlobCopiedSuccessfully)
            {
                log.LogInformation("Blob copied successfully. Now deleting source blob...");
                await sourceBlobClient.DeleteAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```